# Dark Oak Trees are not growing even though all requirements are met

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can't figure out why these trees aren't growing. They have been planted for a VERY long time. There is sufficient light. They have enough space around and above them. I've dumped a whole stack of bonemeal and they still don't grow.

Any ideas?

[image: Tree1]

[image: Tree2]

Comment: @colorfusion correct me if I'm wrong, but the time becomes irrelevant if the asker has used a lot of bonemeal already.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To grow dark oak trees, you need 4 saplings in a 2*2 box. A single dark oak sapling will not grow on its own, regardless of how long you wait or how much bone meal you use on it.

[image]

In this image, the saplings on the left will eventually grow to form one dark oak tree. The sapling on the right will never grow.

Comment: Good information, haven't read that before. I'll try it out and post back. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Tyvm :)

Comment: The magical master of trees...

Comment: In some versions growing trees can be a bit buggy past the common 1x1 seedling.

Comment: Also should mention that you need to have *no grass or blocks* beside the saplings otherwise this will interfere with the growth.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one dark oak tree sapling in the formation, it will not grow, because it needs 4 saplings in a **2x2** square to even be able to grow.